# Refresh PHP query using Javascript (or Jquery?)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am actually looking to do a couple things on a page. I need certain text fields to update every so often and pull information I have stored in a database. I am using PHP within javascript to test (or JS in PHP?). I want these fields to update without users refreshing the page. I have looked at a few examples of people asking similar questions, but I don't understand how to implement it for my needs. Here is what I have, and it is not efficient I am sure, but I am trying to understand. Here is what I have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div>Viewers and Followers:</div><div id="demo"></div>


<script>
var myVar = setInterval(function(){myFunc()}, 1000);

function myFunc() {
    var t = "<?php $con=mysqli_connect('myhost','user','pass','myDB'); $myQuery=$con->query("SELECT * FROM streamers WHERE cname='Famiflashmedia'"); $featured = $myQuery->fetch_array(MYSQL_BOTH);?><?php echo $featured['viewers']?> viewers and <?php echo $featured['followers']?> followers!! <?php mysqli_close($con);?>"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have also tried this and got the same results:

```
<?php 
$con=mysqli_connect('myhost','user','pass','myDB'); 
$myQuery=$con->query("SELECT * FROM streamers WHERE cname='Famiflashmedia'"); 
$featured = $myQuery->fetch_array(MYSQL_BOTH);
?> 

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <div>Viewers and Followers:</div><div id="demo"></div>


    <script>
    var myVar = setInterval(function(){myFunc()}, 1000);

    function myFunc() {
        var t = "<?php echo $featured['viewers']?> viewers and <?php echo $featured['followers']?> followers!!"
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
<?php 
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

What happens is it never seems to resend the query to get the latest results. It refreshes the text (at least I think, because I tried with a ALERT function that popped that function up every 3 seconds with all the PHP in it and never updated). Any advice as to what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: PHP is run once on the server, then never again. To run repeated updates, you need [AJAX](http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/) -- or possibly just [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load)

Comment: @Blazemonger Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I was able to achieve what I needed using this example here http://www.aleixcortadellas.com/main/2009/02/11/232/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is run once on the server, then never again. To run repeated updates, you need [AJAX](http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/) -- or possibly just [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load).

---

First, place your PHP in a separate file and call it whatever you want -- `myfile.php` for this example:

```
<?php 
$con=mysqli_connect('myhost','user','pass','myDB'); 
$myQuery=$con->query("SELECT * FROM streamers WHERE cname='Famiflashmedia'"); 
$featured = $myQuery->fetch_array(MYSQL_BOTH);
?>
<?php echo $featured['viewers']?> viewers and <?php echo $featured['followers']?> followers!! <?php mysqli_close($con);?>"
```

Then use jQuery to update some part of the page from that script on a regular schedule:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div>Viewers and Followers:</div><div id="demo"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
var myVar = setInterval(myFunc, 1000);

function myFunc() {
    $("#demo").load('/path/to/myfile.php');
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just tested your response, this is great! Thank you! Here is what I also tried and it worked, yours is much more clean, I love it! http://www.aleixcortadellas.com/main/2009/02/11/232/

Answer (score -1):

This PHP page you have built will allow you to display database information once only when the page is loaded.  If you want to update your page dynamically you might look into "AJAX" loading a separate PHP page containing your database query and displayed results into a Div on the current the page. You can do this with Javascript alone

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

or jQuery has a fairly decent implementation of this with the load() function.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you could refresh the page using meta tags? for intstance:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
```

This would refresh the page every 30 seconds.

Comment: The goal is to refresh part of the page *without* reloading the entire page.

Comment: Ah, I see. My mistake, sorry. In that case Ajax is the way to go.